# Promise.resolve().then( vs Promise.resolve(

Tags: typescript, promise, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I'm working on some Azure Functions - I'm reading in some documents from a CosmosDB, the performing some actions on those documents.

I've come across the following code, however don't really understand it.

- Why is the `then()` being used, can it not just be removed and the code to perform whatever actions I want directly within the `resolve()` section?

So:

```
const promises = documents.map(document =>
        Promise.resolve().then(async () => {
            // Do some stuff on the document
        })
);

return Promise.all(promises).then();
```

vs:

```
const promises = documents.map(document =>
        Promise.resolve(async () => {
            // Do some stuff on the document
        })
);

return Promise.all(promises).then();
```

Comment: The `.then()` also seems suspicious, maybe this isn't the best code to learn from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you should use neither; instead go for

```
const promises = documents.map(async document => {
    // Do some stuff on the document
});
```

Your first snippet unnecessarily constructs an immediately resolved promise only to chain a function to it. This defers the computation to occur asynchronously, which might be done on purpose but should be mentioned in a comment - and one would just use `async document => { await void 0; … }` for that, avoiding to mix the two promise styles.

Your second snippet constructs a promise that fulfills with a function - that's not what you want.